# Write.csv using Action buttons

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

So basically I am trying to make a small setup of sorts and once a certain analysis is done, I would want to export a certain dataset generated to a predefined location and a predefined name (based on the inputs selected earlier). For this purpose, I used the action button which when clicked does this,

```
observeEvent(input$export_button, {
        write.csv(input_dummy_data4ads,paste0("Dummy Files/",unique(input_dummy_data4ads$Dependent_Variable),"_", unique(input_dummy_data4ads$Model_Type),"_", unique(input_dummy_data4ads$AGM),".csv"),row.names = F,na="")
           })
```

The issue here is that if I click the action button once, it generates the desired csv file and at the desired location too. But after pressing it once, it takes the value of 1 (input$export_button) so when I select a new set of inputs using the radio buttons and generate a new plot based on that (by clicking another action button), the app saves a new csv file with a new name (based on the new inputs) at the desired location. What I am trying to do is to reset the value of the action button so that the new csv file is created only when I click it every time.

I tried to understand this but could not incorporate it https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/167

Answer (score 0):

There are specific functions in *shiny* for this, use `downloadButton` in your *ui* and `downloadHandler` in *server*.

**server.R:**

```
output$export_data <- downloadHandler(
  filename = function() {
    paste0("Dummy Files/", unique(input_dummy_data4ads$Dependent_Variable), "_", unique(input_dummy_data4ads$Model_Type), "_", unique(input_dummy_data4ads$AGM), ".csv")
  },
  content = function(con) {
    write.csv(input_dummy_data4ads, con, row.names = F, na = "")
  }
)
```

**ui.R:**

```
downloadButton("export_data", "Export")
```

Comment: downloadButton doesn't seem to autosave a file I am generating in the server in a pre defined location and a pre defined name. That is why I tried using actionButton which worked (or so I thought) till I realised that it is just working efficiently for the first time.

Comment: @DanSchmidt, based on your comment, I assume you are doing this only on your local machine and not using *shiny-server*, normally these files are transient. It seems you are looking more to reset the `actionButton`, which is just to `isolate` your code, see [this](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/167)

Comment: Sir thank you for replying and well I saw the same link but like I mentioned I was not able to incorporate it.

Comment: @DanSchmidt, if you put up some reproducible code we can see if we can't solve your problem